Prevent dnf from changing cgi-bin directory permissions
We use suexec on an internal server and have SuexecUserGroup set to a restricted user.  But dnf updates of the web server software change the ownership of /var/www/cgi-bin back to root and this breaks our CGI scripts.
Are there any answers besides "don't use /var/www" and "block httpd from updating"?
I am putting forth the argument that, while yes, installers should set ownership and permissions for many things, overriding existing ownership and permissions for what is essentially a recommended user space is not productive.
